# Navigating between pages using MVVM Pattern C# Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm trying to navigate between pages in my Windows 8.1 Store app. I'm realy near the solution, but can't find that specific part wich makes it work. I'm able to push all the nessecary data to my next view, but I am unable to go back.

It looks like something is not right in my navigation structure, but I can't figure out what.

My MainPage.xaml looks like this:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
x:Name="PageRoot"
x:Class="SharePointNews.View.MainPage"
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:common="using:SharePointNews.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="ChevronGlyph">&#xE26B;</x:String>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="GroupedItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="Items" />
    <x:String x:Key="AppName">My Application</x:String>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition />
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridView
        x:Name="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItemsViewSource}}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="310" Height="210">
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource SharePointImageConverter}}"
                               Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" />
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                                   Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid GroupPadding="0,0,70,0" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                            <Button x:Name="HeaderButton"
                                    Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                    AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                    Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}"
                                    Click="HeaderButton_Click">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderTitle" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10"
                                               Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}"
                                               TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
                                               Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}"
                                               TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>

    <!--Vertical scrolling list only used when snapped-->
    <ListView
        x:Name="itemListView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        Margin="0,-10,0,0"
        Padding="10,0,0,60"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard80ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="7,7,0,0">
                            <Button
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}"
                                Click="HeaderButton_Click">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10"
                                               Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
                                               Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="BackButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=PageRoot}"
                Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"
                   Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
    </Grid>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Filled" />

            <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackButton"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ItemGridView"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Padding">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="96,137,10,56" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <!--
                The back button and title have different styles when snapped, and the list representation is substituted
                for the grid displayed in all other view states
            -->
            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackButton"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PageTitle"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemListView"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ItemGridView"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

The code-behind of my MainPage.xaml is this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : LayoutAwarePage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void HeaderButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewsSite list = (NewsSite)(sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;

        ((MainViewModel)DataContext).HeaderClickCommand(list);
   }
}
```

My MainViewModel is this:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Fields
    private RelayCommand _headerClickCommand;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public IList<NewsSite> Items { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        GetData();
    }

    public void HeaderClickCommand(NewsSite list)
    {
        var content = Window.Current.Content;
        var frame = content as Frame;

        if (frame != null)
        {
            frame.Navigate(typeof(GroupDetailPage), list);
        }
        Window.Current.Activate();   
    }

    public async void GetData()
    {
        GroupManager GM = new GroupManager();

        var groupsLoadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GM.GetGroups());
        Items = await groupsLoadTask.Result;

        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods


    #endregion
}
```

My GroupDetailPage.xaml is this:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
x:Name="PageRoot"
x:Class="SharePointNews.View.GroupDetailPage"
DataContext="{Binding GroupDetails, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SharePointNews.View"
xmlns:common="using:SharePointNews.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="ItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid -->
    <GridView
        x:Name="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,136,116,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsViewSource}}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="310" Height="210">
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource SharePointImageConverter}}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="BackButton" Margin="39,59,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                    AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="{Binding GroupName}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                    IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,30,40"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

The conde behind of my GroupDetailPage is this:

```
public sealed partial class GroupDetailPage : LayoutAwarePage
{
    private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
    private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();

    public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
    {
        get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
    }

    public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
    {
        get { return this.navigationHelper; }
    }

    public GroupDetailPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
    }

    private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Assign a bindable collection of items to this.DefaultViewModel["Items"]
        NewsSite group = ((NewsSite) e.NavigationParameter);
        ((GroupDetailViewModel)DataContext).GetData(group);
    }

    #region NavigationHelper registration

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

And finally my GroupDetailViewModel is this:

```
public class GroupDetailViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Fields

    private NewsSite _newsSite;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public List<NewsItem> Items { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public GroupDetailViewModel()
    {
    }

    public async void GetData(NewsSite group)
    {
        _newsSite = group;
        GroupName = _newsSite.Title;

        Items = _newsSite.Items.ToList();

        //Items = _newsSite.Items;

        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => GroupName);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods



    #endregion
}
```

I Hope anybody can help me out here.

Answer (score 6):

After hours of trial and error development I finally found the bug in my code.

In the MainPage.xaml, I declared pageRoot as the name of the page. 
In the GroupDetailPage.xaml, I also declared pageRoot as the name of the page. 
Because of this, I overwrited the pageRoot, and wasn't able to go back.

Anyway, for all you readers, don't forget to give your page a proper and understandable name! It might prevent failures in your code.

Cheers!

Comment: "would've" is short for "would have", not "would of"